Kernel mode driver assembly
I am trying to call inline assembly from a kernel mode Windows driver, but I keeps giving me a linker error and I can't seem to fix it.
I recreated the error in another very small project:
https://github.com/Jules707/DriverAssembly.
This is the error I am getting:

How can I fix it?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

This looks like C++ code, where function names are coded like MainAsm@@YAXXZ to allow for overloaded functions. Either compile as C, or declare the function extern "C" from C++.

Since you are compiling as C++, the compiler is name mangling. To prevent MainAsm from being mangled in source1.asm change extern void inline MainAsm(void); to extern "C" void inline MainAsm(void); for C linkage.

Why is it declared inline?

Another tip that has not been given yet: a repo illustrating the problem is welcome, but on Stack Overflow the main piece of problematic code must also be in the question. Questions that are not self-contained are closed here, since links frequently break.

The problem seems to be name mangling. As your file has a .cpp extension, the compiler assumes it contains C++ code (and assumes it also references C++ code). In C++, you can have several functions with the same name, each one of them with a different set of parameters. Because of this, the compiler generates a reference for a very specific version of MainAsm() (even when you just have one). You can see this in the error message: the linker is looking for a symbol strangely called MainAsm@@YAXXZ.
Try something like this (in the .cpp):
extern "C" {
   void inline MainAsm(void);
}


You can read under "How different compilers mangle the same functions", here. One example, using Visual C++, is just like yours.
